# Can't install PHP extension with pecl because of perl "symbol lookup error"

Tags: php, linux, perl, mongodb, fedora

I am trying to install the mongodb driver for PHP on my Amazon Linux server. I am currently running php 5.4 and have installed php54-devel. When I try to run "sudo pecl install mongo", I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Istack_sp_ptr
```

I get the same error when I just run "cpan" so I think it's deeper than just the PHP extension.

Comment: That means you're trying to use a module that was installed using one build of Perl with another build of Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by deleting /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto and running cpan again. I don't know much about perl, but from my research it seems that there must have been an incompatibility due to a previous upgrade.